# Refresh Graph on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-chart-kit

I am trying to create a button in my app which will refresh random data in a graph (made using react-native-chart-kit) using a React Native Button Component. My Code is below:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Switch, Dimensions, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { LineChart } from "react-native-chart-kit";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Colors from "./constants/colors";


export default function App() {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
  const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);

  function refresh_data(){
    ...
    //Code here?
    ...
  }

  return (
    <View style = {styles.screen}>
      <View style = {styles.button}>
        <Button
          title="Refresh"
          color={Colors.primary}
          onPress={() => refresh_data}
        />
      </View>

      <View style = {styles.graph}>
        <View style = {{flex: 1}}>
          <Text style = {styles.text}>Bezier Line Chart</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{flex: 2}}>
        <LineChart
          data={{
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
            datasets: [{
              data: [
                Math.random() * 100,
                Math.random() * 100,
                Math.random() * 100,
                Math.random() * 100,
                Math.random() * 100,
                Math.random() * 100,
                Math.random() * 100,
                Math.random() * 100,
                Math.random() * 100,
                Math.random() * 100,
                Math.random() * 100,
                Math.random() * 100                
              ]
              }]
          }}
          width={Math.floor(Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.6)} // from react-native
          height={220}
          yAxisLabel="$"
          yAxisSuffix="k"
          yAxisInterval={1} // optional, defaults to 1
          chartConfig={{
            backgroundColor: "#e26a00",
            backgroundGradientFrom: "#fb8c00",
            backgroundGradientTo: "#ffa726",
            decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
            color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
            labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
            style: {
              borderRadius: 16
            },
            propsForDots: {
              r: "6",
              strokeWidth: "2",
              stroke: "#ffa726"
            }
          }}
          bezier
          style={{
            marginVertical: 8,
            borderRadius: 16
          }}
        />
      </View>

    </View>

  </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
  flex: 1,
  alignItems: 'stretch',
  justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  button: {
  alignSelf: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  flex: 1
  },
  graph: {
  flex: 3,
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

I'm pretty new to Javascript and React so this is likely a pretty basic question and I'd like to learn more than anything. One think I tried was having the entire page reload using location.reload() but that isn't what I am looking for (i know because it have a switch in another part of the app which refreshes the data whenever it is clicked, I just can't figure out how). Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some initial "random" data to component state, and in the `refresh_data` click handler set state with new "random" data.

*Also, the correct syntax for setting* `onClick` callback is `onClick={refresh_data}` *or* `onClick={() => refresh_data()}`*.*

```
export default function App() {
  const [randomData, setRandomData] = useState([
    Math.random() * 100,
    Math.random() * 100,
    Math.random() * 100,
    Math.random() * 100,
    Math.random() * 100,
    Math.random() * 100,
    Math.random() * 100,
    Math.random() * 100,
    Math.random() * 100,
    Math.random() * 100,
    Math.random() * 100,
    Math.random() * 100                
  ]);

  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
  const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);

  function refresh_data(){
    setRandomData([
      Math.random() * 100,
      Math.random() * 100,
      Math.random() * 100,
      Math.random() * 100,
      Math.random() * 100,
      Math.random() * 100,
      Math.random() * 100,
      Math.random() * 100,
      Math.random() * 100,
      Math.random() * 100,
      Math.random() * 100,
      Math.random() * 100                
    ])
  }

  return (
    <View style = {styles.screen}>
      <View style = {styles.button}>
        <Button
          title="Refresh"
          color={Colors.primary}
          onPress={refresh_data}
        />
      </View>

      <View style = {styles.graph}>
        <View style = {{flex: 1}}>
          <Text style = {styles.text}>Bezier Line Chart</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{flex: 2}}>
        <LineChart
          data={{
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
            datasets: [{ data: randomData }]
          }}
          width={Math.floor(Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.6)} // from react-native
          height={220}
          yAxisLabel="$"
          yAxisSuffix="k"
          yAxisInterval={1} // optional, defaults to 1
          chartConfig={{
            backgroundColor: "#e26a00",
            backgroundGradientFrom: "#fb8c00",
            backgroundGradientTo: "#ffa726",
            decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
            color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
            labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
            style: {
              borderRadius: 16
            },
            propsForDots: {
              r: "6",
              strokeWidth: "2",
              stroke: "#ffa726"
            }
          }}
          bezier
          style={{
            marginVertical: 8,
            borderRadius: 16
          }}
        />
      </View>

    </View>

  </View>
  );
}
```

There's a lot of repetition though, so I'd also create a random data utility:

```
const createRandomData = (length = 10) => Array(length)
  .fill()
  .map(() => Math.random() * 100);
```

```js
const createRandomData = (length = 10) => Array(length).fill().map(() => Math.random() * 100);

console.log(createRandomData(3));
console.log(createRandomData(6));
console.log(createRandomData(12));
```

New usage:

```
const [randomData, setRandomData] = useState(createRandomData(12));
...
setRandomData(createRandomData(12));
```

Comment: @arc-menace Was this able to resolve your question?